# Lead's affinity for oxygen in the cupellation refining process

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, metallurgy

My inorganic chemistry textbook<sup>1</sup> says:

> Cupellation is a process, where crude gold is taken in a small bowl called cupell and melted in the presence of air. Due to high oxygen affinity of $\ce{Pb}$, it is converted to $\ce{PbO}$ (volatile) and escapes from the system.

Now, the affinity for sulphur and lead is explained by HSAB (soft acid-soft base). But how to account for the affinity of oxygen (hard base) and lead (soft acid)?

#### References

1. Guha, Sudarsan. Concise Inorganic Chemistry for JEE (Main and Advanced). 4th ed., Wiley India Pvt. Ltd., 2017.

Comment: More important is general resistance of noble metals to oxidation.

Comment: @Mithoron Yes that is true, but noble metals generally resist reacting with most elements, don't they? While I have looked thorough a few books about cupellation,and they all talk about lead's affinity for oxygen, and I'm not quite sure about the rationale for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed if you do the cupelation, the lead will form litharge and some parts of the litharge will volatilize.

But usually the cupel is made out of bone matter - this is very porous.

While the molten lead and the gold will stay in the cupel, the litharge will be absorbed by the cupel like a sponge.

If all lead is converted to litharge and all litharge is absorbed by the cupel only the gold shall be left - so far to the theory.